# Symfony JMSSerializer Accessor call service function

Tags: php, rest, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle

I have an Entity *UserProfile* that contains a field *profileImage*, that ist a fileKey

When my REST Controller gets called and needs to render a Board, that contains somwhere a UserProfile Object, i want that it returns a complete URL with the fileKey.

As far as i cannot use Services etc. in Entities, i thought if its possible to call a Service through the Accessor?

http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor

How could i call a e.g. Service within an accessor? Or are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a service in the accessor you will need to inject the service into the entity, or use a static facade to call a service. This is not advisable as it tightly couples the entity with the service.

Instead consider to [use a custom type](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers) for the property, e.g. ProfileImageUrl, and inject the service to the handler. This way the image name transformation shifts to the representation layer, where it belongs.

The handler may look like following:

```
class ProfileImageUrlHandler implements SubscribingHandlerInterface
{
    public function __construct(Service $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function getSubscribingMethods()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_SERIALIZATION,
                'format' => 'json',
                'type' => 'FQCN\Of\ProfileImageUrl',
                'method' => 'serializeProfileImageUrlToJson',
            ),
        );
    }

    public function serializeProfileImageUrlToJson(JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor, ProfileImageUrl $imageNAme, array $type, Context $context)
    {
        return $this->service->buildUrl($imageName);
    }
}
```

In Symfony you can use any service as a handler by tagging it as [docummented here](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/configuration#handlers):

```
<service id="service_id" class="Service">
    <tag name="jms_serializer.handler" 
         type="FQCN\Of\ProfileImageUrl" 
         direction="serialization" 
         format="json"
         method="imageToUrl" />
</service>
```

And finally, you have an option to use the service in the [post_rserialize event](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/event_system#serializer-post-serialize). The documentation suggests the links should be added there, but to my taste it lacks visibility, and smells like magic.

Comment: Thanks! When you say "this is not advisable" you mean the Facade or the idea of injecting a service into a entity?

Comment: Both. The idea to use a router in the entity to build urls is quite far from the best practices, as it requires extra dependencies and tightens links between components. It doesn't matter how the service is invoked - injected via constructor, setter, or called statically. If it is being used in the getter at all, it makes the model dependant on it. Models shouldn't do View's job.

Comment: Working with the EventSubscriberInterface was what i needed. profileImage was just a string, so the jms_serializer.handler wasnt suitable. Thanks again!